# Atualizar useEffect da página navigation.goBack?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-router, react-hooks, expo

Estou desenvolvendo um `App` em `ReactNative` utilizando [Expo](https://expo.io/), porém não consigo atualizar o `useEffect(() => {}, [])` da rota anterior vinda de `navigation.goBack()`.

*Exemplo:*

Aqui tempo a página Index.

```
function Index(){
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  useEffect({
     ...
  }, []);
  return(
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Info')}>
        Index
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Aqui virá a página Info

```
function Info(){
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  return(
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
        Info
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Acontece que no momento que volta para **Index** vindo da página **Info** o `useEffect` da página **Index** não se atualiza.

Existe alguma forma de fazer esses `hooks` atualizar?

Pacotes instalados:

- expo: 37.0.3,
- expo-cli: 3.18.0,
- @react-navigation/native: 5.1.5,
- node: v12.13.0,

Comment: Já leu sobre **[Navigation events](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/)**? Nunca desenvolvi em React Native, mas talvez isso sirva pra você

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O evento deve ser criado sim com `useEffect` mas, o evento é do componente de navegação instalado no projeto `@react-navigation/native: 5.1.5,` seguindo o código de exemplo contido na [documentação](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/):

```
function Profile({ navigation }) {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      // do something
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);

  return <ProfileContent />;
}
```

Pode configurar 3 eventos: `focus` (
Este evento é emitido quando a tela entra em foco), `blur` (
Este evento é emitido quando a tela fica desfocada) e `state` (
Este evento é emitido quando o estado do navegador muda) e no seu caso da pergunta é o evento `focus`.

Answer (score 0):

A maneira simples de fazer isso é exatamente como foi dito pelo 'Virgilio Novic'.
Em resumo, na tela que você deseja voltar, no useEffect você escreve:

```
const [load,setLoad] = useState(true)

useEffect(()=>{
   //Chamada de outras funções
   navigation.addListener('focus', ()=>setLoad(!load))
},[load, navigation])
```

Eu tenho um estado 'load' para carregar as funções todas as vezes que eu precisar. Cada vez que 'load' mudar, o 'useEffect' é chamado. No caso, como o `navigation.addListener('focus',...)` está sendo chamado quando a minha tela volta, eu faço com que ele mude o 'load', fazendo com que o meu 'useEffect' recarregue todas as minhas funções.